# Nested structures in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Is there any significance behind allowing the visibility of nested structures outside the structure in C but not in C++? I did not find any reference or relevance.

```
struct a
{
  struct b{
  };
};

int main(){
  struct b var;  // allowed in C not in C++.
}
```

Comment: In C++ you would use `a::b var;`

Comment: Somehow I never realized there was a difference...

Comment: Wasn't the operator:: introduced only in C++ along with the very notion of different scopes?

Answer (score 36):

It is valid in C because C has a single namespace in which all nonlocal types (i.e., types not declared in functions) are defined; there is no scoping of types using namespaces or nesting.

In C++, type `b` is nested as a member of class `a`, so its name must be qualified with the scope in which it is declared.

Comment: Doesn't C have two separate global namespaces for scalar type names and for structs or something like that?

Comment: @KerrekSB:  Yes, in a sense.  The namespace in question here is the tags namespace (in `struct a { };`, the tag is `a`).

Comment: See ISO C99, 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers, paragraph 7 on the scope of struct in C99.

Comment: An example of the usage would be nice.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the ability to reference nested structures outside of the structure was removed in C++ to improve data hiding. If you need to access a nested struct externally, then it probably shouldn't be a nested struct in the first place.

Wikipedia says: "In both C and C++ one can define nested struct types, but the scope is interpreted differently (in C++, a nested struct is defined only within the scope/namespace of the outer struct)." ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++)). It doesn't say *why*, but at least it acknowledges the difference.

You can use the namespace resolution operator to access the struct, however.

Comment: The *why* seems to be avoiding namespace pollution. From http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/sibling_rivalry.pdf: "In C, structure scopes that appear to be nested aren’t, because structure names declared inside are considered to be in the outer scope. This proved to be unmanageable in C++ where nested classes were often
used as implementation details. Consequently, C++ adopted nested structure scopes."

Comment: +1 for "probably shouldn't be a nested struct in the first place".

Answer (score 4):

because b scope is inside a, you have to use `struct a::b` instead (and unlike in C, the struct keyword is optional).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot declare anything without a scope in C++
In your example
struct b lies inside the struct a, compiler doesn't know where to find struct b

you have to use

```
struct a :: b var;
```

In C there is no restriction for scope, but C++ ensures a restriction