# Typedef-name conflicts with struct tag in C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef

This is my second investigation about structure declaration in C++. (The first is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363980/scope-of-structure-declared-defined-within-another-structure)) But now I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c/18054549#18054549). Specifically I am not sure why this is perfectly fine in C but not in C++.

```
typedef struct{
    int one;
    int two;
}myStruct;

struct myStruct; //forward declaration fails

void blah(myStruct* pStruct);
```

The code above compiles fine on my Ubuntu box with GCC. I reason that it is because the first `myStruct` lives in the normal namespace where function, variable names live. The second `myStruct` lives in the **Tag** namespace. When compiler sees `myStruct*` in the function prototype, it searches in both namespaces and found `myStruct` in the normal namspace and that name happen to be a `typedef` name, so it can be a valid type specifier. The second `myStruct` can be defined later as whatever the programmer wants to be. There won't be any confusion/collision with the first **unnamed** `myStruct` since the programmer has to use `struct myStruct` to refer to the second one.

But in C++, according to the discussion found in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c), my understanding is that the first **typedef** `myStruct` lives in the normal namespace as usual. The second `myStruct` also lives in
the normal namespace(no specific **tag** namespace in C++?) but can be overshadowed by other identifiers. So my question is why wouldn't the first `myStruct` which is in the same namespace as the second `myStruct` shadow the second `myStruct`?

In a more general sense, other than explicit namespaces introduced by the programmer using the namespace facility provided by the C++ language, are there any pre-defined namespaces disambiguating the use of identifiers (including tags, labels, typedef names, object/functino identifiers) like in C? (C has 4 namespaces pre-defined found in my first investigation). Can I find these in the C++ standard stating where these names belong?

**EDIT**: It seems I didn't ask the question clear enough. All I want to know is

1) Which namespaces (if there are such defined in the language) do Lables, typedef names, tag names of struct/union/enum, normal function, normal variable/object name belong? (If I missed any other kinds of name, please add.)

2) Why can normal function name, normal variable name shadow tag names, while tag names can NOT.

3) If there is any clauses in C++ that specify the name spaces like in C ([Section 6.2.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf))

Comment: Why do you need a `typedef` for a `struct` in C++? It's implicit, in the sense that the `struct`'s tag automatically defines a name that does not require a `struct` prefix.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Look at the linked question. I just want to figure out the difference between c and c++ on this regard.

Comment: And it is about why forward declaration will fail using the typedef version. and all the namespace differences between C and C++.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well if u look at the linked question, it says typedef a struct will prevent accidental shadowing by function name, variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, you cannot use `struct myStruct` to refer to a tagless structure which has been `typedef`ed.  And you cannot define a different `struct myStruct`, because the name collides with the typedef name.

If you add the tag, then both `struct myStruct` and `myStruct` alone will refer to the type, in both C and C++:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    int one;
    int two;
} myStruct;
```

Here there is no collision in C++ because the name resolves to just one type, and this is specifically allowed by a special rule.  C++ Standard section 7.1.3 includes the following rules:

> In a given non-class scope, a `typedef` specifier can be used to redeﬁne the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to the type to which it already refers.
>
> If a typedef speciﬁer is used to redeﬁne in a given scope an entity that can be referenced using an elaborated-type-specifier, the entity can continue to be referenced by an elaborated-type-specifier or as an enumeration or class name in an enumeration or class deﬁnition respectively.
>
> In a given scope, a typedef specifier shall not be used to redeﬁne the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to a diﬀerent type.
>
> Similarly, in a given scope, a class or enumeration shall not be declared with the same name as a typedef-name that is declared in that scope and refers to a type other than the class or enumeration itself.
>
> [ Note:  A typedef-name that names a class type, or a cv-qualified version thereof, is also a class-name (9.1). **If a typedef-name is used to identify the subject of an elaborated-type-specifier** (7.1.6.3), a class definition (Clause 9), a constructor declaration (12.1), or a destructor declaration (12.4), **the program is ill-formed**.
> — end note ]

Comment: The question is more on the reason behind it. Namely, where are all these names belong and why they cause collision. And why forward declaration fails.

Comment: @Rich: They collide because the same name is used for two different purposes **in the same scope**.  Shadowing only occurs between different scopes.

Comment: Not in C though. that is why I am asking why C++ differs in this regard with C. where does it say in C++ that tag names have to live in the same space as the typedefed one? And is there a summary to discuss all the "pre-defined" name spaces in C++, if there is such a clause in the C++ standard?

Comment: @Rich: In C they are not the same name.  One is `myStruct` and the other is `struct myStruct`.

Comment: In C it is not b/c they have different name, it is b/c they live in different namespace. In the question, I specifically asked why the typedef name wouldn't shadow the tag name? But function name, variable name CAN.

Comment: Here is the rule in C++: "A class declaration introduces the class name into the scope where it is declared and hides any class, variable, function, or other declaration of that name in an enclosing scope (3.3).  If a class name is declared in a scope
where a variable, function, or enumerator of the same name is also declared, then when both declarations are in scope, the class can be referred to only using an elaborated-type-specifier  (3.4.4)."  C does not introduce the class name into scope as a type-id.

Comment: Scope and namespace are not exactly the same, right? Only within the same scope and same namespace can u even talk about all these rules, right? I want to know more about the space part. See my edit of the question. And thanks for the quick answer and exact reference. Btw, the reference only mentioned scope...where does it say about the spaces of names?

Comment: @Rich: None of this has anything to do with C++ namespaces.  There are several kinds of identifiers in C, and C aficionados sometimes refer to them as existing in separate namespaces, but one can't simply start throwing that term around in a C++ question.  C++ has a language feature and keyword `namespace`, which is a scope, and not related to identifier kinds in any way.

Comment: So there is no such concepts in c++ on the "kinds" of identifiers? If so that is good to know. One less thing to worry and only to pay attention to scope rules..in C++.

Comment: @Rich: There is a distinction still between these kinds, but they are definitely not called *namespaces*, and a bare identifier will search them all.

Comment: I am confused again. Can u provide me some reference on the "kinds" of identifiers? What u mean by "search them all" is that all the kinds of identifiers within scope are searched when a name is encountered in the program?

Comment: @Rich: Well, right there in my answer there are rules that differentiate between class names and typedef-names.  Unfortunately I don't know of any complete list, the rules for them are all over the Standard.  And yes, I mean that when a name is encountered, the search will include all different kinds of identifiers.

Comment: So basically in C++, except in certain cases, like typedefs, no identifiers in scope should be reused? Just to confirm, labels in C++ do not somehow get its own space, so should not have the same name as, say, a variable name or any name that is in the same scope. Is my understanding right?

Comment: From a readability and keeping your sanity perspective I wouldn't reuse any names. Technically I think labels are still separate (there's really no syntax where they could be confused)

Comment: I see. I would like to strive for sanity :P. I am asking just for learning. C++ rules are more complicated than C...