# Will this create an object of Sales_data, or it will create variables inside the class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a 13 year old who's trying to learn C++. I bought C++ Primer and I came across something confusing for me:

```
struct Sales_data {/**/ } acum, trans, * salesptr = nullptr;
    struct Salees_data {};
    Salees_data accumm, transs, * salessptr;
```

I do understand what is a struct and class but I have no idea what this statement will do.
Will it create objects of the Sales_data struct, or it will create variables inside the Sales_data struct?

Comment: Recomended google: "Nested structs".  Here is an similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284167/nested-structures-in-c-and-c

Comment: there is no nested struct. just some strange indent.

Comment: You are very right. My bad! See Ted Lyngmo's answer. TLDR; One liner declaring two objects SaleesData. One object pointer to a saleesData obj (null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This defines a `Sales_data` struct and

- `acum` and `trans` - Two `Sales_data` instances
- `salesptr` - A `Sales_data` pointer, initialized to `nullptr`

```
struct Sales_data {/**/ } acum, trans, * salesptr = nullptr;
```

---

This defines a `Salees_data` struct and

- `accumm` and `transs` - Two `Sales_data` instances
- `salessptr` - A `Salees_data` pointer, uninitialized

```
struct Salees_data {};
Salees_data accumm, transs, * salessptr;
```

> or it will create variables inside the Sales_data struct?

No, there are no member variables in either of the class definitions.

I say *class* definitions because `struct`s are classes too, only with a different default access specifier (`public` instead of `private`).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @apetrai Great, you're welcome!

Comment: Whew. Came real close to triggering a Cars flashback there.

Comment: @user4581301  A "_Cars flashback_"? What's that? I don't get the reference ... I do work with cars though :-)

Comment: [Apologies for leaving out the The](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_What_I_Needed)