# clang DeclContext::getParent() not returning parent RecordDecl for nested structs

Tags: clang, llvm, libtooling

I'm using the following code get parent struct of a nested struct using clang libtooling.

```cpp
bool VisitRecordDecl(clang::RecordDecl *RD) {
    llvm::outs() <<"\n\tTrying to get parents of "<<RD->getNameAsString()<<"\n\n";
    clang::RecordDecl *Parent = dyn_cast<clang::RecordDecl>(RD->getParent()); 
    if(!Parent) {
      llvm::outs()<<"NULL RecordDecl with dyn_cast\n";
      clang::DeclContext *DParent = RD->getParent(); // trying to find what did getParent return
      llvm::outs()<<DParent->getDeclKindName()<<"\n"; // prints TransaltionUnit
      DParent->dumpDeclContext(); // prints whole source file
    }
    else{
      Parent->dump();
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the source file in which I run the code

```c
struct outer{
        struct inner{
                int ia;
                int ib;
                struct deep{
                        int da;
                }dobj;
        }iobj;
        int oa;
}oboj;
int main(){
        return 0;
}
```

For each invocation of `VisitRecordDecl`, `getParent` returns a `TranslationUnit` which cannot be casted into `RecordDecl` to get parent struct of inner or deep struct. `getLexicalParent()` returns `RecordDecl` correctly but why is `getParent()` not working?

Comment: What is the name of the source file?  That affects whether it is treated as C or C++, which could be important here.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak This is being run on a .i file obtained after preprocessing a .c file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DeclContext`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclContext.html)
`getParent` method returns the "semantic" parent.  Although the concept
of semantic parent has some quirks (see the `getLookupParent` method
implementation), to a first approximation, the semantic parent of `B` is
`A` if `B` can be found by qualified lookup as `A::B`.

But the code in question is being interpreted as C, not C++ (per a
clarification in a comment), and C does not have qualified lookup at
all!  C does allow structure definitions to appear inside other
structure definitions, for example:

```
struct Outer {
  struct Inner {
    int i;
  };
  int o;
};
```

but the effect is semantically the same as if they had not been nested:

```
struct Outer {
  int o;
};
struct Inner {
  int i;
};
```

In particular, to name the inner type in C, one writes just `struct Inner`,
not `struct Outer::Inner`.  See C99 6.7.2.1p7 and compare to C++11 9.2p1.
See also the question
[Nested structures in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284167/nested-structures-in-c-and-c).

Consequently, `getParent` returns the
[`TranslationUnitDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TranslationUnitDecl.html)
for both
[`RecordDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecordDecl.html)s.

As you've noted, you can instead use the `getLexicalParent` method to
get the syntactic context in which the declaration appeared.

If you compile the code as C++, either by changing the file extension
to one that `clang` recognizes as being C++ (such as `.cc` or `.cpp`),
or pass the `-xc++` command line option to the command line parser,
then the semantic parent of `Inner` will be reported as `Outer`.